# Is it possible to style a html select drop-down like this and still keep it mobile friendly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First, this is what the drop-down should look like:

[image]

This should be just a normal html `select`

```
<select>
  <option>January</option>
  <option>February</option>
  <option>March</option>
  ...
</select>
```

There's probably some JQuery component library out there that I can use, but what I also want is that when you're on mobile, e.g. Android, iOS, etc... that the mobile browser will handle the display/ineraction of the select box, rather than having the user interact with the drop-down as it is displayed in the screenshot... In other words, this styling should only apply for desktop.

Comment: There are plenty of mobile compatible open source plugin `https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=select%20plugins%20jquery` .

Comment: Can I suggest revising the question to make it clear early on that you're asking *how* to maintain mobile-compatibility? I think that's what you're asking, but it's easy to miss that above. Perhaps opening with something like "I want to style a select list to within an inch of its life, but not interfere with mobile browsers providing their own UI for it." (probably not phrased quite *my* way ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

So you want one element to be displayed on desktop, and a different one displayed on mobile, why not have them both in the markup and display a different one via CSS depending on the size of the screen?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px){
    #select-box{
        display:inherit;
    }
    #dropdown-box{
        display:none;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 761px){
    #select-box{
        display:none;
    }
    #dropdown-box{
        display:inherit;
    }
}
```

Something like that? note that display:inherit should be whatever display the element is having by default.